# Is there a platform that facilitates the per-topic separation of conversations?

Tags: communication-management

On Slack I'm having conversations about different aspects of the project I'm working on with my colleagues (either private or room conversations). Sometimes I need to know everything that has been said about a particular aspect of the project though. But there's no way to do that because it's often all in the same room or the same private history. And keyword search can sometimes be ineffective to remember an entire conversation about a specific topic.

Is there a project management platform/app that solves this problem?

Comment: You are seeking software recommendations. These kinds of questions are [off-topic here](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You can try to ask your question at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tools that help to apply structure on a debate/conversation:

- [bCisive](https://www.bcisiveonline.com)
- [Debategraph](http://debategraph.org/Stream.aspx?nid=61932&vt=bubble&dc=focus)
- [Cartagrapher](http://cartargrapher.appspot.com)

They probably don't solve your issue, however they could help.

As a side note I think it's the matter of discipline that could help most. Slack channels should do the job, but they don't for some reason. People share their ideas in the context of conversation, not necessarily in the context of a Slack channel. There is randomness and creativity. One need to apply reasoning to connect loose pieces of information. I'm actually glad computers don't do it.